# ember.js: Correct way to select a tab and keep content

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to use emberjs but I'm stuck in some stupid errors.

I didn't find a good way to select a tab. Should I set some variable in the route and use bindAttr in the handlebar? (I tried it but didn't work). I need to create a emberjs view for each element that I need to interact with template and use {{#view}}{{/view}}?

In the 'navigation' outlet, I render signup/signin forms and want to keep filled data when user change the selected tab. How can I do that?

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/alexandrebini/6g7Xu/24/

Sorry if I was not clear, I'm a little lost...

Comment: I can't image what the relationship between the signup/signin forms and navigation tab, maybe you can setup a demo in http://jsfiddle.net/tualatrix/FEvSc/ ?

In ember.js, you can follow the rule for one View, one controller, and binding them together.

Comment: I din get your question properly,Do you want to generate a tabbed view using Ember JS with routing ?

Comment: I`ll have a overlay with a sidebar and 2 tabs: signUp and SignIn. When user click in one table, the right content of overlay changes.
Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/alexandrebini/6g7Xu/24/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Bindings & also Ember provides their textfield views which are pretty handful...I edited some of your fiddle to account your issue, rest of fiddle I think you can handle by yourself, http://jsfiddle.net/6g7Xu/26/ (Edited the Sign In part use this to edit the Sign up view)

Hope this helps !

Comment: Thanks! got it... So, I have to use this views for every input/select/etc in my application? What about keep the sidebar tab selected?

Comment: you can do these with html tags too like <input type="textfield" {{bindAttr value="signInUsername"}}> & so....but using Ember elements makes you maintain less code & it has got it's own benifits...For example consider {{view Ember.Select contentBinding="someArray"}} instead of hardcoding the tags for the number of elements in the array..I hope you got my point

Comment: regarding sidebar tab selected... http://jsfiddle.net/5WcAu/ This is what you mean ?

Comment: What should I do if I want to keep the 'isHomeSelected' and 'isSignInSelected' in my view instead of directly in app? like this: http://jsfiddle.net/alexandrebini/M9AmN/1/  and this would be a good practice? I'm asking this because I willl have other views in this app, for example: when user is logged in he will see other tabs and forms (that's why I had two outlets in the first jsfiddle)

Comment: yes the good practise is to put inside views, but you can put them in your applicationView or Controller as a computed property may be...In a nut-shell, put your tabs in applicationView, controller the CSS using applicationController & clicking should call a method in router...If it's not clear will update the fiddle when  get some spare tym

Comment: One more good practice is to perform all the calculations inside the controller rather than views...